# Choose which product category should be used in Woocommerce URL

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

I am building a Woocommerce webshop and for some products there are 2 categories on the same "level" in the category hierarchy. I want the breadcrumb and URL to use one specific category out of these 2 categories. I have tried to set the category I want to "primary" in the category list, but that does not help. Can I change the category's priority somehow?

I use this custom setup for the url: /produkt/%product_cat%/ which works fine for all product urls except for some where Woocommerce choose the "unwanted" category, out of 2 possible "same level" categories, for the URL.

So, how do I make Woocommerce choose the category I want?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/10562/199395

Answer (score 0):

I only wanted to post my super simple solution in case more people struggle with this. If you just delete the product category you don't want to appear in URLs and breadcrumbs and then add it again (and of course re-assign it to the products in question), the ID of that category will now be so high that it does not appear in URLs and breadcrumbs, when competing with other cats on the same level in the hierarchy.